# Confusion regarding visa type of Ireland

Tags: ireland

I'm an Indian student and I'll be visiting the Insight Centre at NUI Galway, Ireland from May to July end (<90 days).
My professor and the administrative assistant advise to apply for a short stay tourist visa with the reason being "**Other**" and the purpose stated as "**Research Visit**". To support my stay, they will provide me a studentship of 1200 euros per month. Now, some people said that it'll be rejected if I apply for this type of visa and rather, I should apply for an internship visa. But when I do so (by selecting reason as "**Internship**"), in the application portal I end up in a page that asks me my **Employment Permit/Atypical Working Scheme Number**. It is mandatory to enter before I proceed to the next page.
So I'm confused as to what visa type I should apply for.

To clear up my motive, I'll be visiting Insight for less than 90 days starting from May and I'll receive 1200 euros per month studentship. And My purpose is "**Research Visit**" and I'll not be working to get salary there. 
It'll be very helpful if someone can clear up my confusion and I'll be grateful to them.
Thank you!

Comment: It’s not clear from your question who will pay you the 1200€ per month?

Comment: "some people said that it'll be rejected" -- who? Your professor/school gave you advice and it sounds rather reasonable.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas  Two senior from my institute who had visited Insight centre a few years back. Apologies for not being clear in the question. 
I agree that my professor's advice seems reasonable. I just got very confused with the mixed responses I was getting.

Comment: @Traveller The Insight Centre for Data Analytics ( which is affiliated with NUI Galway) will help me with my living expenses by providing me a studentship(tax exempt) of 1200 euros per month. Sorry for not being clear in the question.

Comment: As you do not get an answer on travel, I move this question to expatriates, where they are more specialized in questions about visa for studying and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the Embassy and they too instructed me to fill "Other" as the reason of travel and submit all the relevant documents. Although they did not give me the exact reason why, after consulting with many people I can safely conclude that it is because that I'm not going to work there and I will not receiving any salary. Rather I will be receiving a studentship which is tax exempt. The confusion arose because of some new changes in the AVATS portal where if you select "Internship" as the reason you have to enter your Work permit number thus meaning that Internship is accounted under work and what I'm going to do is a Research Visit as a visiting student.